# files folder compare / search in all subfolders for Windows / Linux

Tags: windows, linux, file-management, file-synchronization, file-search

I would like to have an application for comparing contents of two folders to check if they contains same files. For Windows or Linux.

I've tried WinMerge.org, however, it compares folders for identical structure - that is it looks for contents of folders of 1st location only in same relative path folders of 2nd location.

I want an application for each folder/file in 1st folder to search for same name/time/size entries in 2nd folder's all structure / all subfolders. No need to verify contents of files now and no need to have merge functionality, just a report.

Ideally for each subfolder in 1st folder when some files from it found somewhere in 2nd folder, it would write line like 35% by size, 45% by quantity match found and if not 100% then list of all found files/subfolders in results tree branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about comparing folders themselves, and just want to **find duplicate files**, then look for a "find duplicate" program, like [FDUPES](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) (it's [old home](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/)) or [RDFind](http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/).

---

[Kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) compares folder trees & their files, and works in linux & windows too. It does have merge abilities too, but works excellent as a "diff" only program.

In most linux distro's it's available in a standard repo, or it's homepage has more info & source code.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

BeyondCompare is another option. But it is commercial licensed.

It is however, inexpensive.  [Download here](https://scootersoftware.com/)

It will also handle FTP transfers and copying between Windows and Linux with regards to attributes and end of lines.

[image: Folder Compare Screen]